# What is RowIndex in WADLogs table?

Tags: azure-diagnostics, azure-tablequery

How is RowIndex calculated in azure diagnostic WADLogs table ? 
I saw that it is not in a consecutive order across rows. Is it a randomly generated unique number ?

RowKey contains RowIndex as its last segment of its string. Knowing how RowIndex is calculated would help me query WADLogs table based on rowkey (which is indexed).

Comment: Did you manage to generate the RowIndex ?

Comment: no. i did not get any conclusive answer on this.